# Write headers in mutiple R output files

Tags: r

I would like to 3 write headers in multiple R output files. The files should look like this:

```
details_URL= File created from xxxxx, source data www.john.com
```

The next header should get the input from a variable i.e.

```
description= variable1_variable2
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
header <- rbind("header1", "header2", "header3")

for (i in 1:3){
    write.csv(x = header, file = paste0("file",i,".txt"))
}
```